# Need Help in debugging a simple swing app using JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, graphics2d

I am trying to develop a swing application which looks like the following :-

[image]

(The demo for this application can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html))

The black square moves as the cursor is moved .The ComboBox entry selects the topmost layer in the stack,above which the square will appear during movement but below the remaining next top layers.

I have completed it nearly but the black square(image) is vibrating when mouse is moved (motion is not smooth) and also its motion is confined to small area and it is not moving over complete layered pane.Also there is no effect of changing settings in ComboBox or CheckBox.

Here is the code :-

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class JLayeredPaneDemo implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener{
private String layerString[]={"Red(0)","Yellow(1)","Blue(2)","Green(3)","Orange(4)"};
private Color layerColors[]={Color.RED,Color.YELLOW,Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN,Color.ORANGE};
JComboBox jcb;
JCheckBox jcheck;
JLayeredPane layeredPane;
ImageIcon img;
JLabel cursor;

public static void main(String args[])
{
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new JLayeredPaneDemo();}});
}

public JLayeredPaneDemo()
{
JFrame frame=new JFrame("JLayeredPane Demo");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

frame.add(createControlPanel());
//frame.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
frame.add(createLayeredPane());

try
{
    img=new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/watermark.png")));
}catch(IOException e){System.out.println("ERROR LOADING IMAGE :"+ e);}
cursor=new JLabel(img);
cursor.setBounds(45,45,img.getIconWidth(),img.getIconHeight());
cursor.addMouseMotionListener(this);
layeredPane.add(cursor,new Integer(2),0);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel createControlPanel()
{
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Select the Settings"));

jcb=new JComboBox(layerString);
jcb.setSelectedIndex(0);
jcb.setActionCommand("LAYER_SETTING");
jcb.addActionListener(this);

jcheck=new JCheckBox();
jcheck.setSelected(true);
jcheck.setActionCommand("FRONT_BACK");
jcheck.addActionListener(this);

panel.add(jcb);
panel.add(jcheck);

return panel;
}

public JLayeredPane createLayeredPane()
{
layeredPane=new JLayeredPane();
layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Layered Pane : Move Your Mouse"));
layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,310));

Point origin=new Point(20,20);
int offset=35;

for(int i=0;i<layerString.length;i++)
{
    JLabel label=createColoredLabel(layerString[i],layerColors[i],origin);
    layeredPane.add(label,new Integer[i]);
    origin.x+=offset;
    origin.y+=offset;
}

return layeredPane;
}

private JLabel createColoredLabel(String str,Color color,Point origin)
{
JLabel label =new JLabel(str);
label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
label.setOpaque(true);
label.setBackground(color);
label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
label.setBounds(origin.x,origin.y,100,100);

return label;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
String cmd=e.getActionCommand();
if(cmd.equals("LAYER_SETTING"))
{
    int position=jcheck.isSelected() ? 0 :1;
        layeredPane.setLayer(cursor,jcb.getSelectedIndex(),position);
}
else if(cmd.equals("FRONT_BACK"))
{
    if(jcheck.isSelected())
        layeredPane.moveToFront(cursor);
    else
        layeredPane.moveToBack(cursor);
}
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//Do nothing
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
cursor.setLocation(e.getX(),e.getY());
}
}
```

Please Help me to find the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to cite the [demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your `mouseMoved()` implementation no longer applies the offsets used in the original; you'll need to supply them based on the geometry of the `Icon` used in your `cursor`.

```
//Adjustments to put Duke's toe at the cursor's tip.
private static final int XFUDGE = 40;
private static final int YFUDGE = 57;
...
//Make Duke follow the cursor.
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    dukeLabel.setLocation(e.getX()-XFUDGE, e.getY()-YFUDGE);
}
```

Addendum: *I don't understand why I didn't get any error when I used the wrong brackets? Can anyone point out the reason, please.*

```
layeredPane.add(label,new Integer(i));
```

Because the language [defines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2) an array as an `Object`, the compiler chose the matching  available [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
public void add(Component comp, Object constraints);
```

Comment: :So what's the problem ,i don't understand?If i don't use xfudge and yfudge ,it will only be slightly displaced !!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two silly mistakes which consumed my 11 precious hours.

1)I set actionListener for 'cursor' instead of layeredPane and that's why the movement was confined to a small area.

2)Secondly,i wrote `layeredPane.add(label,new Integer[i]);` instead of `layeredPane.add(label,new Integer(i));` .(Notice the square brackets).

Comment: But i don't understand why i didn't get any error when i used the wrong brackets ? Can anyone point out the reason please.